# Conditional rendering in ReactJS between button and normal text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have one object array say `defect` and now if the status of the defect is open then it should show as button and it should read close the defect and if it is closed, then instead as button it should just mention as closed.
So, here `statusRender` is the issue and is now working as expected in the last column. Cant figure out what I am missing. Any leads?

```
render() {

  if (defect.defect_status == 'open') {
    statusRender = <button key={index} data-id={defect.id} onClick={() => this.showAlert(defect.defect_id)}>{defect.defect_status}</button>;
  } else {
    statusRender = { defect.defect_status };
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Defect ID</th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.state.defectList.map((defect, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td> {defect.defect_id}  </td>
                <td>{defect.defect_category}</td>
                <td>{defect.defect_description}</td>
                <td>{defect.defect_priority}</td>
                <td> {statusRender}
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })
          }
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: try to use === instead of == and ternary operator instead of if else . Ternary operatore won't make a difference but it's better practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `user1095118` removing the semi colons did the job. I was missing the correctness of the curly braces which solved the issue

```
{ 
          defect.defect_status == 'open' 
           ?<button key={index} data-id={defect.id} onClick = {() => this.showAlert(defect.defect_id)}>{defect.defect_status}</button> : defect.defect_status
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

it is a scope issue you cannot declare defect outside of the map function

```
{this.state.defectList.map((defect,index) => {
 return (
    <tr key={index}>   
      <td> {defect.defect_id}  </td>
      <td>{defect.defect_category}</td>
      <td>{ defect.defect_description}</td>
      <td>{ defect.defect_priority}</td>
      <td> 
        { 
          defect.defect_status === 'open' 
           ? <button key={index} data-id={defect.id} onClick = {() => this.showAlert(defect.defect_id)}>{defect.defect_status}</button>;
           : defect.defect_status;
        }
      </td>    
    </tr>
   );      
 })
}
```

Comment: Actually earlier I was trying this only. But it didnt work. Here is the codepen link. https://codepen.io/the_keshav/pen/QVYEoe

Comment: It appears to be working in your codepen. however I am not sure what the login page is for but you need to change the ReactDOM.render to App ?

Answer (score -1):

If you just need to access status string instead of the button maybe you should remove brackets in your if else statement

```js
render() {

   if(defect.defect_status=='open') {
  statusRender = <button key={index} data-id={defect.id} onClick = {() => this.showAlert(defect.defect_id)}>{defect.defect_status}</button>;
} else {
  // No brackets here ? 
  statusRender = defect.defect_status;
}
      return (
        <div>
        <table className="table table-bordered table-hover">
           <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Defect ID</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Priority</th>
              <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
        {this.state.defectList.map((defect,index) =>{
         return(
         <tr key={index}>   
        <td> {defect.defect_id}  </td>
        <td>{defect.defect_category}</td>
        <td>{ defect.defect_description}</td>
        <td>{ defect.defect_priority}</td>
        <td> {statusRender}
          </td>    
       </tr>
         );      
        })
}
</tbody>
     </table>
          </div>
          )


  }
}
```